# How to check if a file is already included?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a procedure structure like this:

```
<someprocedure.p>
    <randomCode>
    <INCLUDE standardIncludeFile.i>
</someprocedure>
```

The `standardIncludeFile.i`-include file can be used with any procedure files. However, it requires other include files to work. F.ex. `stantarderror.i` and `standardconstants.i`.

If the `someprocedure.p` already has included these 2 files, they shouldn't be `included` in the `standardIncludeFile.i`. If they're not, they should be `included` in the `standardIncludeFile.i`.

Can I use `DEFINED` inside the `standardIncludeFile.i` to check if those `.i`-files are already `included` in the `someprocedure.p`?

If I use `INCLUDE` anyway without any conditions, the Eclipse Open-Edge editor gives me the setting to `include once`, but I'm not sure if that's a good way. The files are compiled on the server for production, anyway.

Currently `stantarderror.i` or `standardconstants.i` do not contain any `GLOBAL-DEFINED` constants, so I cannot check them that way with `DEFINED`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within your incldue file, do something like this

```
&IF DEFINED (stantarderror) EQ 0 &THEN
GLOBAL-DEFINE stantarderror stantarderror


// actual code here


&ENDIF
```